# Voltage to current converter using transconductance amplifiers, OPA860 and OPA861

Tags: analog, current-source, converter, transconductance

I want to generate an ac current signal of 100 \$\mu\$A(peak to peak) with a bias current of 50 \$\mu\$A  upto 100MHz frequency. This will be the input to a \$20 k \Omega\$ load.

I searched for some wideband transcondutance amplifiers on TI website and I got OPA860 and OPA861 ([link](http://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/special-function/transconductance/products.html?keyMatch=transconductance%20amplifier&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything)). In the link, under the output current, all of the amplifiers feature a minimum of 15 mA. Clearly, these cannot be used for my circuit, so to make myself sure, I checked the datasheets of these two amplifiers if there is any way to control this current...

In the 4th (3rd) page  of OPA860 (OPA 861), it can be seen that for \$R_L = 500 \Omega\$ and \$R_{ADJ} = 250 \Omega\$ (used to adjust the quiescent current) under OTA output performance that `C-Output current sinking/sourcing is a minimum of \$\pm 15m\$A'.

I think these IC's cannot be used, but I am not sure if that is the case. Is there any way to control this current?

Comment: That's a minimum across all the samples of the part that you might buy of the maximum current they're able to source or sink.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, it means they they can't be used to source/sink 50 \$\mu\$A bias current, right? Initially, I designed a V-I converter using OpAmps, but I could not use it because it severely limited the bandwidth. Thus, I was looking for some other alternatives and thought transconductance amplifiers might be it. But looks like they can't be used.

Comment: It means you can't use them to source more than 15 mA. 50 uA is less than 15 mA, so you should be okay. But notice there's about a 2x uncertainty (maybe trimmable?) in the gain, so it might be fussy to get 50 uA consistently from board to board.

Comment: On the other hand, this is a fairly esoteric part. There are probably ways to do this with op-amps that will be more mainstream (and cost less). I know of op-amps with up to 5 GHz bandwidth, so I would expect the bandwidth you want to be achievable.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will look more into it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Either the title or the first sentence is not correct. Is your input a current and do you want a voltage output? Then is a current to voltage converter. Is the output a current and the input a voltage? Then it's ok the title (but the first sentence needs to have "output" instead of "input").

Comment: @next-hack Thank you for pointing that out. I want to generate an ac current signal with voltage as an input. The current generated will be the input to a load. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: I have another question: will that 20k-Ohm load have also a capacitance (to ground)? Because I think that in this case it could be difficult to achieve a 100MHz bandwidth.

Comment: @next-hack You are right, the capacitance of the load may effect the bandwidth. In my case, the capacitance might be at most 50 fF. The pole comes out at 159 MHz.

Comment: I calculate from 20k-50p a pole at 159 **k**Hz (and not **M**Hz)...